# I am trying to set Active SIM for calls, sms and data programatically

Tags: android, shell, adb, tasker

Android 13 stock and rooted- duel sim.

I am trying to set Active SIM for calls, sms and data. However, I want to set ACTIVE SIM, regardless of which SLOT the card is in, and to achieve that I need to use the sim card ID "ICCID number".

The usual way, is to assign a specific sim slot with :

```
settings put global multi_sim_voice_call 1
settings put global multi_sim_sms_call 1
asettings put global multi_sim_data_call 1
```

But theoretically assigning an ICCID number as the active/preferred sim, will set the simcard with the ICCID as activ, regardless of which slot the simcard is in. So going in to android settings and simcard settings, here you can choose which SIM card should be prioritized for calls, SMS and mobile data. So runing a Logcat during ths manual change of sim card --

you can below clearly see that the ICCID is being used: 994608992[****] and is changed to: 594601402[****] ... It must be possible to set these values through: "settings put global multi_sim_voice_call" somehow ????. Right ...??

```
DataDefaultSubscriptionController:
getDefaultSubscriptionInfo: {id=2 iccId=994608992[****] simSlotIndex=0 carrierId=1695
displayName=Work carrierName=OpenSub nameSource=2 iconTint=-14408298 number= dataRoaming=0 
iconBitmap=android.graphics.Bitmap@4c868c1 mcc=240 mnc=08 countryIso=se 
isEmbedded=false nativeAccessRules=null cardString=994608992[****] cardId=1 isOpportunistic=false
groupUUID=null isGroupDisabled=false profileClass=-1 ehplmns=[] hplmns=[] subscriptionType=0 
groupOwner=null carrierConfigAccessRules=null areUiccApplicationsEnabled=true}
```

```
KeyguardUpdateMonitor:
SubInfo:{id=1 iccId=594601402[****] simSlotIndex=1 carrierId=2287 displayName=KONTANT
carrierName=OpenSub nameSource=2 iconTint=-3251991 number= dataRoaming=0
iconBitmap=android.graphics.Bitmap@cdb1ff8 mcc=240 mnc=01 countryIso=se isEmbedded=false
nativeAccessRules=null cardString=594601402[****] cardId=0 isOpportunistic=false groupUUID=null
isGroupDisabled=false profileClass=-1 ehplmns=[24001, 24005] hplmns=[24001, 24005]
subscriptionType=0 groupOwner=null carrierConfigAccessRules=null areUiccApplicationsEnabled=true
```

I tried: **settings put global multi_sim_voice_call 1234567123456** "ICCID" number, but that didn't work.

I have tried using the "ICCID" sim card number:

```
settings put global multi_sim_voice 1234567123456
settings put global multi_sim_sms 1234567123456
settings put global multi_sim_data 1234567123456
```

I have also tried:

```
settings put global multi_sim_voice_iccId 1234567123456
settings put global multi_sim_sms_iccId 1234567123456
settings put global multi_sim_data_iccId 1234567123456
```

Didn't work. Any ideas I can try out ??